# Update Multiple columns?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I want to update multple columns if it reaches my condition for e.g

i want to do something like

```
set column1 ,column 2 ,column 3
if column1=0 if column2=0 if column3=0;
to column1=somevalue,column2=somevalue,column3=somevalue;
```

Below is my query which works for 1 column only iwant to do this for more then 1 columns but in the same query.

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("UPDATE DwH_Staging_table SET pestpopulation1=@avg_pest1 

WHERE DistrictName=@DistrictName and TownName=@TownName And VarietyOfCrop=@V_Crop  And 
pestpopulation1=@pest", con1);

cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@avg_pest1",row[3]);

cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DistrictName", row[0].ToString());

cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TownName",row[1].ToString());

cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@V_Crop",row[2].ToString());

cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pest",0);

cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to set your columns if **ALL** existing values are 0, you can do it in one query

```
UPDATE mytable
SET column1 = @value1, column2 = @value2, column3 = @value3
WHERE column1 = 0 AND column2 = 0 AND column3 = 0
```

But I'm guessing you want to set them separately if each column **separately** equals 0. In this case, you need to execute 3 separate queries.

```
UPDATE mytable
SET column1 = @value1
WHERE column1 = 0

UPDATE mytable
SET column2 = @value2
WHERE column2 = 0

UPDATE mytable
SET column3 = @value3
WHERE column3 = 0
```

Comment: e.g column1 value is 0 and column2 is 9 and column3 is 0 i want my query to check this row only one time.not multiple times because it will take too much time for alot of data

Comment: Then you can modify the first query and replace zeroes with your values.

Comment: But if i do that it replaces all the values i want only some of the values being replaced but not the others
e.g if column=0, column=9, column=0;
i want to replace the columns with 0 to some avg!!

Comment: More over the number of comparisons in my case become too high as my data is quite huge and i want to reduce these comparisons to save time .
so i can not use update like in the second example you gave !

Comment: Sorry, then you have to do separate queries. You use one query if you want to update values separately. It just doesn't work this way.